# data-step attribute not working in jquery knob

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

How to change data-step attribute in **jQuery knob**. I have tried `data-step="25"` in input html tag, but it's not working. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vishnur15/6SH5t/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are not linking correct js file for knob in your fiddle:

Try this js link:

http://anthonyterrien.com/js/jquery.knob.js

then `data-step="25"` working well.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6SH5t/2/)